# WooCommerce - When sale price is 0, show only regular price

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've been looking for solution on this for ages. I have a WooCommerce website where I do bulk product uploads. Now, from my excel sheet, I have a column for regular price and sale price. For some products without a sale/promo price, the client has replaced it with 0.

After uploading the excel file, I realized that those products with sale price of "0" are showing as "Free". I want a situation when the promo price is 0 or below a specific number, it should only show the regular price instead.

Comment: **The simplest way:** You can make easily a function that will replace in database for all existing products `sale price "0"` by `sale price null`. You will run this function only once. This way you will get all  `sale price "0"` updated to `null` to avoid this problem. You can even unset the sale price when `sale price == "0"` for all products.

Comment: Great. Thanks for your help. Much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the help so far... I found this code and it did the magic!

```
add_action ('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'check_sale_price', 40 );
add_action('woocommerce_before_single_product', 'check_sale_price', 40 );
function check_sale_price() {
global $product;
if ( $product->sale_price == '0' ) {
  $price = $product->regular_price;
  $product->sale_price = $price;
  $product->price = $price;
  global $wpdb;
  $wpdb->get_results( 'UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value='.$price.' WHERE meta_key="_sale_price" AND post_id='.$product->id, OBJECT );
  $wpdb->get_results( 'UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value='.$price.' WHERE meta_key="_price" AND post_id='.$product->id, OBJECT );
}
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to upload the same price for regular and sales price. That way the sales price will not be shown.

Comment: Great. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. I re-imported prices as 0,0 (or 0.0 whatever applicable) instead on 0. That helped to resolve the issue.